# How do I resolve or ignore React Strict Mode warnings in Redux-connected components?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When I wrap a Redux-connected component inside `React.StrictMode` and replace the usage of `componentWillReceiveProps` with `getDerivedStateFromProps`, I still get this error in the console:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: Please update the following components 
    to use static getDerivedStateFromProps instead: 
    Connect(MyComponent)
```

I'm using the latest version of `react-redux` (5.0.7). Is there any way I can resolve or ignore these warnings, or do I have to wait until `react-redux` is updated?

Comment: There is an open `react-redux` issue to resolve the warnings in that package: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/897

Comment: A workaround is to wrap the component in `React.StrictMode` before passing it to `connect()()`. The drawback of this approach is that you need to put a `React.StrictMode` tag in each component instead of just once at the root `App` component.